# Rails paperclip problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, flv

I have uploaded the video into my rails application by using thoughtbot-paperclip then the video is converted into "flv" format by using ffmpeg.   For your reference here I specified some of my model sample code:

```
model.rb:

has_attached_file :source,:styles => {:thumb => "137x85>" }
```

If i specified `:url` or `:path` option it doesn't worked correctly.

In my view I played my video by using the following line:

```
<%= @model.source.url.gsub(/\?.*/,'')%>
```

If i use  `<%= @model.source.url%>`, the video is not played.

When do the puts for video url it shows me the video URL as /source/original/sample/sample.fly?22000009.  I knew that the last portion is a timestamp, but i want to use `<%= @model.source.url%>`. What's my mistake here can any one correct me please?

Comment: You're not being very clear here. Do you mean @model.source.url return the path with the timestamp and you don't want it ?
If so, did you know that there is a caching system and if you remove the video, the users' cache will never be updated when you update the video.

Comment: I formatted the code the best I could without knowing a thing about RoR.  Someone else may want to check and correct.

Comment: Hi dmathieu thanks for your response.. yes i mean @model.source.url returns the path with the timestamp. In my view truncate the timestamp by using <%= @model.source.url.gsub(/\?.*/,'')%>. Is this the correct method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Paperclip documentation](http://rdoc.info/projects/thoughtbot/paperclip) says that you should be able to turn off the timestamp for Paperclip::Attachment#url by passing false as a second argument:

```
url(style = default_style, include_updated_timestamp = true)
```

For style, you probably need to specify Paperclip::Attachment.default_style (not sure about this and I don't have a system I can use for testing).

Answer (score 1):

I achieved desired result by calling

```
attachment.url( attachment.default_style, false)
```